# Error in Assigning proper home directory while configuring jboss-eap-6.4 server in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss6.x

when adding a jboss-eap-6.4 version server in Eclipse luna, i added the below home directory. 
D:\jboss-eap-6.4.0\jboss-eap-6.4:

which contains all the subfolders (bin, bundles, docs, domain,modules, standalone etc).

But I am getting  error :  'User must select a valid configuration'

If I am starting the server using command prompt it's happening properly.

D:\jboss-eap-6.4.0\jboss-eap-6.4\bin>standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml
I am using jre6 in eclipse

Please advice.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Will's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 37):

I just had this problem, clicked in `JBoss Community`, `JBoss AS 6.x` and got the same error. Clicking in `Download and install runtime...` and it only gave me 6.0 and 6.1 option.

Then I returned to the `Define a new server` and, instead of `JBoss Community`, chose `Red Hat JBoss Middleware` and proceed to chose `JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6.x` and voilà.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue and resolved the same by using following steps:

1) Open server view

2) right-click, new -> Server

3) Expand the "Red Hat JBoss Middleware" category and select the "JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6.1+" server type.

4) Click 'next'

5) Keep the server marked as "Local" and controlled by "Filesystem and Shell Operations"

6) click next

7) Fill in the runtime's home directory, specifically, point to your unzipped eap6.3 folder.